# No me aparece la opcion "MAS" en MySQL

Tags: mysql

No puedo ver la oocion "mas" en MySQL en WAMPserver, y lo necesito para poder ver las relaciones entre tablas (que no esta configurada)
Me ayudan porfavor?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que se entienda, tu pregunta no es sobre mysql.. es sobre un problema en phpmyadmin... mysql no tiene nada que ver... ahi se ve el mas.. que no ves vos?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que no le sale una pestaña que va al lado de Disparadores, llamada "Mas" o "More". Intenta, con el mouse, redimensionar el navegador a ver si es un glitch del responsive, verifica si en otro navegador también sucede. Finalmente prueba [actualizar el phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/2022/5/10/phpmyadmin-520-released/), sobreescribe todos los archivos excepto el config.inc.php